# Is it possible to enable the green center-line alignment guides in Microsoft Word on MacOS?

Tags: macos, microsoft-word, user-interface, alignment

In Word for windows it is possible to get this nice green line showing when something is centered:
[image]
This setting is controlled by the option "Use alignment guides" as shown here:
[image]
However, when using Word for MacOS there are no green lines and the corresponding menu has no such option:
[image]
Is there any way to turn on that green line for word in MacOS? Or is this feature just missing in the Mac version of the software?

These screenshots were created using the latest versions of Word 365 as of May 2023 on Windows and on Mac.